# inherit method throws error

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following super class:

```
   abstract class ContactQueue
{

    public abstract DateTime period { 
        get; set; }
    public abstract String type { get; set; }
    public abstract String toString();
    public String ReWritePeriod(String choice) 
    {
        new CultureInfo("da-DA");
        switch (choice)
        {
            case ("Day"):

                return period.ToString("ddd");

            case ("Week"):

                return ""+period.ToString("ddd")+" Uge: "+weekNumber(period);

            case ("Year"):

                return period.Year.ToString();

            default:
                return "";
        }

    }
    private int weekNumber(DateTime fromDate)
    {
        // Get jan 1st of the year
        DateTime startOfYear = fromDate.AddDays(-fromDate.Day + 1).AddMonths(-fromDate.Month + 1);
        // Get dec 31st of the year
        DateTime endOfYear = startOfYear.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
        // ISO 8601 weeks start with Monday 
        // The first week of a year includes the first Thursday 
        // DayOfWeek returns 0 for sunday up to 6 for saterday
        int[] iso8601Correction = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5 };
        int nds = fromDate.Subtract(startOfYear).Days + iso8601Correction[(int)startOfYear.DayOfWeek];
        int wk = nds / 7;
        switch (wk)
        {
            case 0:
                // Return weeknumber of dec 31st of the previous year
                return weekNumber(startOfYear.AddDays(-1));
            case 53:
                // If dec 31st falls before thursday it is week 01 of next year
                if (endOfYear.DayOfWeek < DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return wk;
            default: return wk;
        }
    }
}
```

And i have the following class inheriting the above class:

```
class Callback : ContactQueue
{
    public int completedCallbacks{get; set;}
    public int completed_within_timeframe{get; set;}
    public int answerPercentage { get; set; }
    public override String type {get; set;}
    public override DateTime period { get; set; }
    public Callback(String type,DateTime period)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.period = period;
    }
    public override String toString()
    {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Now i wanted to test if my inherit method actually worked so i did the following:

```
        Callback cb = new Callback("Callback",start);
        MessageBox.Show(cb.ReWritePeriod("Day"));
```

And at that point my program throws an error!

What am i doing wrong?

**Error message**

```
The invocation of the constructor on type 'Henvendelser.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
```

Comment: And the error is...? And it's happening on what line is...? And once you ran it through the debugger and validated your information, you suspect the problem's general vicinity is...?

Comment: Ive updated my post with the error!

Comment: Almost sounds like it's unrelated. What happens if you remove the `MessageBox`? Just call `cb.ReWritePeriod("Day")` and not report it? EDIT: Is this at all related to the issue you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594172/import-exception)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the error (and the exception's cause) is in the line

```
  new CultureInfo("da-DA");
```

There's no such a culture "da-DA". Do you mean "de-DE" (Germany) or "da-DK" (Denmark)?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx

there is?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Sorry, but all I see there is either `da` or `da-DK`, not `da-DA`.